# Automatic Notification when Google Doc is opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Apps Script that contains the following code:

```
  function onOpen() {
    var emailAddress = "jthfortyone@gmail.com"; 
    var message = "Viewed"
    var subject = "Someone Viewed Your Resume";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

I want to receive an email every time someone views my [resume](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XcGhLZrnFIXlDc5H09uZLlnMcvG7aaaQtCyRsYO4zTc/edit)

But for some reason I only receive an email if I am the one open it and not when anyone else does.

What do I need to change to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container-bound script in a shared document will only run if:

- Sharing has granted edit privileges. (Viewing and Commenting aren't enough.)
- User is logged in with a Google account. (Only scripts run as webapps can be triggered anonymously, at which time they run as the owner. No such option, in this case.)
- User agrees to authorize the script. (A script that sends emails will require authorization.)

Since this is your resume, I think you're going to need to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `onOpen` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) should run in response to the active user opening the document.

The active user is defined as:

> **The user (Google account) that causes a script to execute**. Depending on the execution method **this may be different from the [effective](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/glossary#effective_user) user**. You can also think of this as the user at the keyboard

Have you tried accessing the document with a dummy account?